# Could someone actually survive an F-5 category tornado in this manner?

Tags: realism, twister

In [*Twister*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117998/), there is a scene near the end of the film featuring Bill and Jo strapping themselves onto a metal pipe that apparently goes down into the ground 30 feet.

> Here! These pipes go down at least thirty feet, if we anchor to them
>   we might have a chance!

Bill and Jo then strap themselves onto this metal pipe while an F-5 category tornado goes over them:

**Could someone actually be able to survive a tornado this way?  How did Bill know that the pipes went down into the ground 30 feet just by looking at them?**

Comment: That scene always bothered me for the reasons in Skooba's answer. I mentally chalked it up to "Hollywood being Hollywood and getting science wrong as usual."

Comment: As anyone knows, the proper way to survive a tornado or a nuclear blast is a refrigirator.

Comment: You missed the best part, when it's over, the belt is BROKEN, yet they are still there

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I see many problems with this scene...

On the [Fujita Scale](http://www.tornadoproject.com/cellar/fscale.htm) an F5 tornado's winds are 261-318 miles per hour...

> Strong frame houses lifted off foundations and carried considerable distances to disintegrate; automobile sized missiles fly through the air in excess of 100 meters; trees debarked; steel re-inforced concrete structures badly damaged.

1. **Depth of Pipe:** Sure, the pipes may go down thirty feet, but they are attaching themselves to the horizontal piece above ground. The first failure point will be the elbow joints not the line pipe.
2. **Connection method:** Again, the depth of the pipe will not matter. What will matter is tensile strength of the leather strap they are tied off on.  I am not an expert, but a rough search leads me to believe the [tensile strength of of leather](https://www.westdean.org.uk/study/school-of-conservation/blog/books-and-library-materials/tensile-testing-of-leather) is only 570 Newtons, or about 128 pounds which would not be enough to hold two fully grown adults.
3. **Shrapnel**: All the wood, glass, and metal flying around at hundreds of miles per hour would certainly be enough to pierce the skin and be lethal. If anything I think this would be the most likely cause of death.

As seen above if whole houses are disintegrated, I find it highly unlikely our heroes made it out of that one in one piece, let alone alive.

---

A real F5 tornado in 2011 killed 168 people in Joplin, MO. [Researchers theorize](https://stateimpact.npr.org/oklahoma/2013/08/29/twister-truths-can-nothing-survive-an-ef5-tornado/) that most of the damage caused is from substandard building design.

> That isn’t true. Properly built, above-ground safe rooms — typically a hardened indoor closet or room reinforced with concrete and steel — are just as safe as underground shelters, says Texas Tech’s Ernst Kiesling, who’s also the executive director of the National Storm Shelter Association. In fact, above-ground safe rooms can be safer because they’re more likely to be used when severe storms move in, he says.
>
> There have been no reports of any deaths in properly built above-ground safe rooms, Keisling says.

**For Bill and Jo to survive they would have had to get to a proper shelter.**

Comment: Good answer, but I think there is one piece missing. What is the air pressure like both in the tornado and in the center part that it rotates around? A quick search did not yield anything useful, but I imagine the pressure differences could cause severe damage. Without any science to back it up I would expect ruptured eardrums and possibly even the bends, possibly with fatal consequences. I think it would be worth exploring whether a human could survive the pressures in the tornado as well as the pressure _changes_.

Comment: I think their arms may have survived, as they may remain firmly attached to the pipe. But their bodies would likely have been ripped off at the shoulders, and would not survive the landing impact after falling down from however high they were sucked up. Theoretically, with the right hollywood tech, they could grow their bodies and head from the surviving arm :)

Comment: @Bohemian: without shrapnel flying around, you'd need a lot more windspeed to do that. Stuntflyers and wing walkers and whatnot do stuff that subjects themselves to stronger winds at airshows and they usually stay in one piece.

Comment: @Snowman: nah, the greatest pressure drop ever recorded in a tornado was around 1.5 psi, which is equivalent to diving to 3.5 feet of water. You'll definitely notice it, but it will hardly do anything catastrophic to you.

Comment: The leather strap looked much thicker than the 2mm pure leather you reference. You also don't calculate for bonding material or anything. And they never free hang off the strap, so its not just its strength but add on their strength. It's not like they used a dress belt.

Comment: @cde but the belt is BROKEN at the end, but they are still there

Comment: Just a minor quibble, but [tensile strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_tensile_strength) is measured in units of force *per area*, e.g. newtons per square meter. Claiming that "the tensile strength of of leather is only 570 Newtons" is as meaningless as saying that the top speed of your car is 10 meters.

Comment: @kevin, is it? I haven't seen the movie in years and the video above doesn't include that part.

Comment: Agree about #3.  The winds themselves would likely be survivable.  All the stuff that the wind sends flying at you?  Not so much.

Comment: I looked for a longer clip with that scene but I couldn't find one.  But I distinctly remember noticing it when I watched the film for the first time.

Comment: Okay boys and girls just remember this is M&TV not Physics SE.....

Comment: Most of this analysis is quite mistaken - **buildings fail because they have a lot of surface area in comparison to their strength** and that generates loading forces in directions other than the gravitational one they may be primarily built for.  The part that is right is the danger of being hit by loose things carried in that wind.

Comment: Chris, nothing about my answer is about the building failing. I added an article about a real tornado and the anayalsis about structures  is a quote  from the people who do that for a living and to save people's lives. You guys are digging way too deep on this.

Comment: I’m from Joplin. Lived there all my life. I can definitely say reinforced above-ground shelters are just as effective as below ground. But the whole pipe with leather strap thing in Twister....no. Not even close.

Answer (score 6):

**No**.

*Twister* is a steaming pile of Hollywood horseshit. Almost nothing depicted in this film is realistic.

**First to the *metal pipe*.**

We can realistically estimate the amount of force someone will experience in a F5 tornado. The free fall [terminal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity)  of a human being is approximately 55 m/s (120 mph, 200 km/h). This means that the wind speed has exactly enough force to lift the weight of the human body. Now an [F5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujita_scale#Parameters) starts with 116 m/s (260 mph, 420 km/h) which is the nearly exactly two times the terminal velocity speed. Unfortunately for our daring heroes wind force [*squares* with linearly increasing speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)), so the actual force *quadruples*.

If Bill weighs 1000 N, he is pulled with a force of 4000 N (!). And not with a securely fitting harness used on the thigh like a climber which *can* actually hold this amount of force, but with an improvised leather strap around the upper torso. If the heroes don't get ripped out immediately, they wish they were because the leather will tear off the muscles and ligaments.

What is also wrong is the convenient floating: Tornado wind is highly turbulent, they will be flung around like laundry (Which is the reason why I did not use the higher fall velocity for being head-on; They cannot hold that position). But the pipe does not even budge or bend which is strange when someone realizes that it is being pulled with the weight of approximately 8 humans.

**Next question: What is softer: Tree bark or human skin ?**

Well, all the flying debris does *that* to tree bark (and this was an actual F5):
[image: Some ex-trees. The trees that are still present have few branches and almost no bark.]

I hope the answer to what will happen to two idiots strapping themselves inside an F5 tornado is now clear: They will be mutilated and flayed alive.

Comment: Skin has 3 times the tensile strength of bark. And notice how only part of the bark is stripped, which really depends on the condition of the bark. Old, dried bark is easier to strip then the newer, wetter bark, typically seen on the branches.

Comment: @cde Nice to know, but my claim was that skin is softer, not that it is able to withstand more pulling. Does it change the end result what debris will be doing to open skin ? [This road](https://www.flickr.com/photos/sklee/5659337940) was scoured of tarmac, [this cow](https://s14-eu5.ixquick.com/cgi-bin/serveimage?url=https:%2F%2Fs-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com%2F736x%2F8a%2Fda%2Fd5%2F8adad581390b5f24c30cb380df25f74f.jpg&sp=782b280cbfa7b0c7cac0ec333019f981) survived the F5 Glazier–Higgins–Woodward tornadoes in 1947.

Answer (score 4):

I am inclined to think that one would be required to remove debris from the equation before any answer beyond **"no"** would be possible - as the simplest pieces of debris have shown to be highly penetrative in such a force of nature.

I am certainly inclined to say that strapped in such a matter you would probably flutter around several times which would very likely lead to a fatal clash with the ground, if not some unfortunate whiplash.

Answer (score -1):

@PCARR Is 100% correct. I know because I speak from experience and I know first hand the horrific damage an f-5 does because I lived through one and not just any one but one of the most powerful tornados EVER, Jarrell, TX on May 27th 1997. Anyone who knows anything about tornados or is intrigued by them knows about this tornado as it has done things that have still yet to be rivaled statistically. I will admit when I say I lived through one, I don't mean directly hit but that growing up my family lived in Round Rock, TX and had a dove hunting spot in Jarrell. I was young and in cub scouts at the time so in the aftermath of the tornado, the local scouting community wanted to help and so we were tasked with going around these communities and helping those who had just lost everything. Basically we stayed around cedar park where the tornado had weakened into f-3 damage which was still pretty incredible. The only place we didn't go was Jarrell bc after the tornado,  it was gone.

This is something that you can't really just put in the news and violence the media doesn't usually broadcast because it's brutal and it's just one of those things that if you lived there then you'd know about it bc you were local or knew someone that was directly affected. All I can say is, we never went hunting in Jarrell again afterwards. This is what was witnessed locally and I doubt you might find footage or as clear of a description of what it did to people and structures.. it literally ripped them to pieces. The force of this thing and its power were so overwhelming that to agree with the post about being mutilated is an understatement. I mean I don't know of a word to describe it other than saying it blended people, debris, animals, other things in nature together to where you couldn't even tell the difference between human remains and animal remains. If you were in it during its f-5 strength you witnessed something that there was no advice they give to help keep you safe. There was no innermost room, no above ground shelter, no ditch or any other way to escape and survive a direct hit. You had to be underground. I know some people will say Jarrell, TX "That's out in the boonies" or "Ole southern country" but it's not what you would imagine. These weren't just cheap houses, trailers, and mobile homes. These were well built brick homes with solid foundation too and not only did this tornado wipe the foundations clean of the house... it was so intense it ripped the pavement from roads, bark and limbs from trees and uprooted them. It took parked vehicles and moved/ threw them over half a mile. Someone might want to fact check me if they know where they can validate it to be exact but I want to say it also scoured the ground itself up to 20in maybe just shy of 2ft. I don't recall the exact measurement but it def ripped up ground and by ground I mean earth and pavement as I mentioned earlier. So to say that they would be mutilated is 100% correct and the comparison to sky diving or extreme situations where ppl survive wind speed comparable to an f-5 either there's a calculation issue with comparing the f-5 numbers to the extreme winds exposure situation or the data for one or the other is completely off bc I can guarantee that regardless of sky diving, or strength of leather straps, or skin being stronger that bark or whatever other thing I've read that there is no way to survive a "DIRECT HIT" of one of the inner vortices of a tornado that strength by trying to anchor like that. I believe even without debris it's still impossible. The only way to be directly hit and survive is maybe if you never get hit by any actual vortices and end up still in the tornado but more so towards the outside to where you dodge the strongest parts which is actuality common. I saw an entire house destroyed in the days after the local outbreak.. all but a young girl about my age sitting in a recliner across from where their tv still sat completely unscathed from the rest of the house. She told me what it was like when it hit and that the somehow it left the TV and the chair despite taking walls and roof next to where these things sat.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Wall of text aside, please focus on answering the question and break the text down into paragraphs to make it easier to read (you can [edit] your answer at any time)